# CSS: Aggregating compound selectors that share an ID

Tags: css

I'm writing my external CSS and I have a lot of common styles that are different classes stemming from the same ID. Is there a way I can aggregate them in a single compound selector?

E.g.
From this--

```
#common_id .class_1,
#common_id .class_2,
#common_id .class_3 { declaration; }
```

```css
.class_1 {color: red;}
.class_2 {color: green;}
.class_3 {color: blue;}

#common_id .class_1,
#common_id .class_2,
#common_id .class_3 {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="common_id">
  <span class="class_1">Red</span>
  <span class="class_2">Green</span>
  <span class="class_3">Blue</span>
</div>
```

To something like this--

```
#common_id .class_1 and .class_2 and .class_3 { declaration; }
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:is

Comment: Hello Nicole, could you please share your HTML and CSS code? I believe you are mistaking the usage of id and classes, from reading your code here.

Comment: Adding to @mnemosdev's comment, when you say "stemming from the same ID", do you mean descending from/contained within the same ID?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding a runnable snippet. Feel free to tweak or revert if that wasn't your question.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet. :) Yes that is exactly what my HTML already looks like. I'm asking if there is a shortcut for writing my CSS so that I don't have to keep repeating the reference to the ID with the next class at the beginning of my declaration. It's ok if there isn't- just wondering if there was.

Comment: HI Nicole. I would suggest you to explore SASS (https://sass-lang.com/) to get much more flexibility on writing css. It is similar to css but it makes it much more awesome

Answer (score 0):

Given that the id attribute should be used to reference single elements, and taken into consideration your code, I would suggest the following:

```
#common_id .shared_class { declaration; }
```

This will work for the following HTML structure:

```
<div id="common_id">
    <p class="class1 shared_class"></p>
    <p class="class2 shared_class"></p>
    <p class="class3 shared_class"></p>
    <p class="class4"></p>
    <p class="class5"></p>
</div>
```

The above code will apply to all elements that share the class `.shared_class` under the same `id`. It is a viable solution if your id contains more elements but you don't want to apply the .shared_class CSS to all of them. If you would like to share the CSS with all the children of the element with #common_id, do the following:

```
#common_id { declaration; }


<div id="common_id">
    <any element></any element>
</div>
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Thanks :) I hadn't thought about adding extra classes on the HTML end. Still wondering if it's possible though using just CSS. If I have an extensive page, it could be annoying to go into multiple items and add an extra class.
Yes, this has solved my problem for now, but still wondering if there is a convention within HTML or maybe Bootstrap that will let me do this.
Thanks again

Comment: It highly depends on the output you want to have, if you could post your HTML maybe we could help you better!